# Genric object return from Interface

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can somebody help me to get a generic object from Interface.My implementation is like the code below:

```
interface Itest
{
  T getObject();
}

public class Test1:Itest
{
  public T getObject()
  {
    return (T)(new logger());
  }
}
```

Comment: This code won't compile.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: This code can't be made generic since you always return a `logger` instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typically would need to make the interface generic, then return that specific type from the class, ie:

```
interface ITest<T>
{
    T GetObject();
}

public class Test1 : ITest<Logger>
{
    public Logger GetObject()
    {
        return new Logger();
    }
}
```